# Quarkus: Creating a Gateway microservice

Tags: quarkus

Does anyone know a Quarkus compatible library to create a gateway microservice (such as [Netflix/zuul](https://github.com/Netflix/zuul) or [Spring Cloud Gateway](https://spring.io/projects/spring-cloud-gateway)).

Thanks.

Comment: Hello, did you use camel after all or you found an alternative? I am asking because I am also trying to replace a spring boot 2 zuul api gateway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know what functionalities you all need for a gateway, but if you need a simple mapping/routing functionality, then you can also do this with Camel which has Quarkus support.

See an example here:
https://dzone.com/articles/microservices-with-apache-camel